# Access $refs from other components not in the same level as current component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a Vue application.
It has a header and then the main content.
Nesting and structure as below

```
TheHeader.vue -> TheLogin.vue

MainContent.vue -> ShoppingCart.vue -> OrderSummary.vue
```

I need to access an element in `TheLogin.vue` from `OrderSummary.vue`

```
this.$refs.loginPopover.$emit('open')
```

gives me an error `"Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined"` so obviously I am not able to access `$refs` from other components.

The question is how do I get hold of refs from other components?
Thanks in advance!

Edit 1 - Found out $refs works with only child components.
How do I access elements across components in different level?

Comment: You could try `this.$root.$refs.header.$refs.login...`, assuming every component has refs to its children. Sounds more like a job for a state manager like VueX or maybe an [event bus](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) but I'm not a fan of those.

Comment: Yeah I did not want to use Vuex because I just want the popover to show up if the user is not logged in. Simple task.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You definitely don't want to be reaching through the hierarchy like that. You are breaking encapsulation. You want a [global event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication).

And here's a secret: there's one built in, called `$root`. Have your OrderSummary do

```
this.$root.emit('openPopup');
```

and set up a listener in your TheLogin's `created` hook:

```
this.$root.on('openPopup', () => this.$emit('open'));
```

In general, you should try to avoid using refs.

Comment: But why do you suggest to avoid using refs?

Comment: Because they for situations in which normal Vue control of the DOM will not suffice.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who comes here later and wants to access `$refs` in parent component, not in this particular case for emitting events since event bus or a store would suffice but let's just say you want to access some element in parent to get it's attributes like `clientHeight`, `classList` etc. then you could access them like:

```
this.$parent.$parent.$refs //you can traverse through multiple levels like this to access $ref property at the required level
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put a function like this on your component to do this. I put mine in a Mixin:

```
  public findRefByName(refName) {
    let obj = this
    while (obj) {
      if (obj.$refs[refName]) {
        return obj.$refs[refName]
      }
      obj = obj.$parent
    }
    return undefined
  }
```

I also added some accessors to help:

```
  get mycomponent() {
    return this.findRefByName('mycomponent')
  }
```

And once that exists, you can access your component by simply doing:

```
this.mycomponent
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that tip Abdullah!
In my case I was looking for a sibling, so in case someone comes looking for that, here's an example:

```
var RefName='MyCoolReferenceName';
var MyRef,x;
for(x=0;x<this.$parent.$children.length;x++)
{
  if(typeof this.$parent.$children[x].$refs[RefName] !='undefined')
  MyRef=this.$parent.$children[x].$refs['LABEL_'+bGroupReady.ChildID];
}
if(typeof MyRef !='undefined')
  MyRef.error=true;
```

PS - The reason I'm doing MyRef.error=true is because I was having ZERO luck with Quasar inputs and lazy-rules="ondemand". Turns out you can just set .error=true to activate the error message and the red highlighting and .clearValidation() event to clear it back out. In case someone is trying to do that as well!