# Vue.js 2: how return async callback\promise to a custom $emit event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, promise, async-await

is possible to receive data from the listener of a custom event or just simply wait it is done?

My problem is:

I've a custom event on a component1:

```js
methods: {
  test: function () { 
    //how await and\or get data from the listener?
    this.$emit('foo', ... );
  }
}
```

In another component2 I've a listener to this event which does some async actions.

```js
methods: {
  async beforeMount() {
    this.$on("foo", async () => {
      //some async functions
    });
  },
}
```

What I'd need to do is to wait the completion of the async tasks done by the listener and only then execute some other actions in the method "test" of component1.

Ideally, I'd like to receive the "data" elaborated by the listener in component2 back in the $emit of component1 - there will be only 1 listener for this event so there wouldn't be problems of multiple callback etc.

However, as I'm using Vuex it would fine to just "await" the async tasks - I'd store and  grab the results from Vuex store.

I've tried to use a callback or a promise, but I can't get either working (probably I'm writing them totally wrong).

Is it possible to achieve something like that?
Can someone provide an explanation\example of how doing so?

Thank you

Comment: *"What I'd need to do is to wait the completion of the async tasks done by the listener"* - Absolutely not. Your event emitter must not care who is listening to its events, what they are doing in response to an event, or how long it takes them to finish. You have your dependencies messed up, and instead of trying to bend the event emitter to your will, you need to think about how to restructure your code to resolve that dependency issue.

Comment: I'd agree with your observation, however in this case I don't see a different way to restructure the code, unless re-doing a large part of the app - which is time-wise impossible. In component 2 there's a form validated via vee-validate, while in component1 there's an action that must be done only if that form is valid. So I need to call the async validation from component1 before proceeding with the other operations. Maybe the all the "event" approach isn't correct in this case, but I'm not seeing any other way to do so unless e.g. use a weak tree of $refs

Comment: So your actual question is not *"How can I make an event emitter wait for an event consumer?"*, but *"How can I structure this dependency more wisely?"* - and this requires that you share a more context (i.e. code) about how the things are set up right now.

Comment: *"while in component1 there's an action that must be done only if that form is valid."* - Knowing nothing else, this sounds like component1 could listen to an event from component2. Or maybe, as you've noted yourself, maybe events aren't the right thing to use here.

Comment: Possibly helpful: jQuery's [.triggerHandler()](https://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method "returns whatever value was returned by the last handler it caused to be executed". A similar implementation may/may not be possible in Vue. At least `.triggerHandler()` demonstrates that this kind of thing has been thought of before.

Comment: @Tomalak:  The full context is in [another my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666338/5065842). In short, Component1 must know if the Form in Component2 is valid (async action) before proceeding with his actions. I've asked this question to solve the specific doubt about event\listener, but I'd be happy to receive suggestion on possible different approach to structure\solve this dependency better, if you have any insight (and maybe that other question is the correct place to do so).

Comment: Looking at your other question, something like `await this...shippingAddressForm.validate().then(valid => valid ? this...updateAddress() : false)` resolves to whatever `updateAddress()` returns (in case the address is valid), or false. I believe a promise chain like this can solve your issue. Note that the `.then()` callback may return either a new promise (as it does when the address is valid) or a literal value (as it does when the address isn't). The `await` will wait for the last item in the chain, be it promise or literal value.

Comment: Overall I don't think it's a good design choice to let the client code do the validation. That's something the server code needs to do. Therefore an `updateAddress()` call should be atomic. If the address checks out, the call should succeed, if it doesn't it should fail. The client should not have any influence here. It should submit the address and the server does everything that's necessary and only respond with "OK" or "Error". This way you can side-step the "component1 needs to wait for component2" issue entirely.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry but I don't understand your code example: what do you mean? To keep the chain of $refs, but to replace the if on the result with a resolver of the promise? That would work, but keep the "chain of $refs" that I don't like design-wise.

For your comment about relying on backend instead of front-end: I agree totally with you. Unfortunately we're using a backend system that isn't reliable enough in validating the address and we can't change that. So unfortunately I need to implement a validation front-end

Comment: Typically you put validation on *both* the front-end and the back-end. Back-end validation for security and integrity, front-end for user convenience. But anyway, that was just as side-note. If you have a function that calls another function and then needs to wait until that other function is done before resuming its own work - that's not an event. That's a function call. Don't use events for flow control. Events are meant to be send-only, there is - by design - no return channel. It looks like `this.$emit('foo', ... );` is supposed to be a regular function call into your other component.

Comment: @Tomalak ok thanks for the explanation: the import point (for me) is that I'm using somethings (events) for a functionality they aren't created for. When I'll have the time I'll try to rebuild that part in way I can use a function call or whatever in a more robust way instead of trying to use events.